# WiFi fails after suspend or hibernate

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend, power-management, hibernate

Often when I wake my computer up from suspend or hibernate, the wifi doesn't work. It won't connect to anything. If I click on the icon, it doesn't list any networks nearby, etc. I used to have to restart the computer to get wifi back - which could be a major interruption to my workflow.

My go to with network problems is to try something like this:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

That doesn't work. If I look at `dmesg` after doing this the last line reads

```
[17677.269171] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

I've found one thing that does seem to work consistently, and that is

```
sudo pm-suspend; sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Then, when I wake the computer up a few second later, wifi comes back to life. The interesting thing is I *can't* just put the computer to sleep, wake it up, and then issue the `network-manger` restart command. That does not work. I have to issue the commands together so the network restart is the first thing that happens when the computer wakes up.

**What workarounds or further troubleshooting steps would you recommend?**

`lshw`

```
   description: Wireless interface                                                                          
   product: Wireless 7265                                                                                   
   vendor: Intel Corporation                                                                                
   physical id: 0                                                                                           
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0                                                                               
   logical name: wlx1002b592a48c                                                                            
   version: 59                                                                                              
   serial: 10:02:b5:92:a4:8c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-32-generic firmware=22.391740.0 ip=192.168.1.214 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:126 memory:df100000-df101fff
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
~:$ sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version
Version: 1.157.14
~:$ dmesg -T | grep 'iwl\|WIFI' > iwlnotes.txt
```

Output here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tXQnZxynrW/,  it looks to me like the interesting lines are:

```
[Wed Feb 14 22:30:04 2018] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[Wed Feb 14 22:30:04 2018] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[Wed Feb 14 22:30:04 2018] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled        
[Wed Feb 14 22:30:04 2018] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[Wed Feb 14 22:30:04 2018] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CSR values:
...
[Wed Feb 14 22:30:04 2018] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[Wed Feb 14 22:30:04 2018] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6
[Wed Feb 14 22:30:04 2018] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 22.391740.0
....
[Wed Feb 14 22:30:04 2018] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

After this wifi crash I put a message in dmsg "Attempting WIFI Fix' (you can search for it in the pastebin text) then tried my workaround listed above. Wifi is now working. Oddly enough, it looks like the same dmsg output happens *after* I did my fix as well. But the wifi **is** currently working. So I don't know what's going on.

Comment: After an occurrence, please run: `dmesg | grep iwl` then post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Also, please edit your question to add the result of: `sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version`.

Comment: Ok, I did both.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if the module is loaded with modprobe.  Happened to me a while back same issue, just reloaded the network module